# MATLAB - Recursive Dynamic Programming

Tags: matlab, recursion

I seem to have a problem with my knapsack algoritm on MATLAB. I have several files to add to the storage and they have certain values. I would like to maximize the total value under a certain capacity restriction. 
The values are 10, 40, 30, 50.
The sizes are 6, 4, 5, 3.
The capacity is 10.

When I run the code, I get the optimal total value but I cannot specify which files have been added to the storage. Is there a way to do this? I tried adding the file numbers into an array but it wouldn't work. The array is emptied every time the function is run.
The code I have is as follows:

```
function maxim=addfiles(v,w,cap,n)
maxim=0;
stored=[];
if (cap==0)||(n==0)
    return 
else
   if w(n)>cap
       maxim=addfiles(v,w,cap,n-1);
   else 
       if addfiles(v,w,cap,n-1)<v(n)+addfiles(v,w,cap-w(n),n-1)
       maxim=v(n)+addfiles(v,w,cap-w(n),n-1);
       stored(n)=n;
       else maxim=addfiles(v,w,cap,n-1);
       end
   end
end
```

What I want from the algorithm is to return something like:
Optimal value: 90
Files added: 2,4

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "**maximize** the total computation time"? wouldn't you rather want to minimize it? aside from that, please give examplary inputs for your function as well as the current and the desired output of it.

Comment: I have edited the question so that it has exemplary inputs and outputs. Also, I have changed the question statement so that it makes better sense. Thank you.

Comment: so `v=[10, 40, 30, 50];  w=[6, 4, 5, 3]; cap=10`? what is `n`?

Comment: n is the number of elements, which is four. v, w, and cap are correct.

Comment: The simple solution would be to make store global. A better solution would be to have a second output.

Comment: What do you mean by making store global? Should I add it to the input list?

Comment: see: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

Comment: now all i get is stored=[1,2,3,4].

Comment: I think you need to add something in the else section what to store when n is not taken. I suppose you were trying to implement this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem with recursion instead of loops.

Comment: You can return two things from a MATLAB function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code so it will return the maximum value *and* the selection; not sure if it's more MATLABish than you're used to, but it does the same thing, and is better commented :-D

```
%// Knapsack problem
%// v   = values (non-negative, vector)
%// w   = weights (positive, vector)
%// cap = available capacity (non-negative, scalar)
%// n   = the remaining number of objects (non-negative, scalar)
%//
%// maxim  = max accumulated value (non-negative, scalar)
%// stored = index of stored objects (integer, vector)

function [maxim, stored] = addfiles(v,w,cap,n)

        %// End of recursion
        if (cap==0)||(n==0)
                maxim  = 0;
                stored = [];
                return;
        end;

        %// Above capacity
        if w(n) > cap
                [maxim, stored] = addfiles(v,w,cap,n-1);
                return;
        end;

        %// Alternatives 1/2
        [maxim1, stored1] = addfiles(v,w,cap,n-1);
        [maxim2, stored2] = addfiles(v,w,cap-w(n),n-1);

        if maxim1 < v(n) + maxim2
                %// Adding is good
                maxim  = v(n) + maxim2;
                stored = [stored2, n];
       else
                %// Adding is bad
                maxim  = maxim1;
                stored = stored1;
       end;
end
```

Save in `addfiles.m`, then call with:

```
[maxim,stored] = addfiles([10, 40, 30, 50], [6, 4, 5, 3], 10, 4)
```

Comment: @theakt If you think the posting is correct, chose is as the answer. :-)